# is there any way prevent filter from Google Play for S4 device only ?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

i have made app for all resolution,app will install in all android device and tablets.

i have not set any device and tablets filter for installation on app.

my Question is,

> How i can prevent filter from Google Play for S4 device only ?
>
> it mean app will not show in S4 device only while user search on
> Google Play.

i had also try with Google play Account in device support screen tab but no luck.

does any on have idea, Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check below links. You will be able to filter it.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html
Use S4 specs to run your application on S4

Or you can see the below link that describes how to to do it on Google Play
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1286017?hl=en

Comment: Thank for reply, but i want to restrict app for S4 only out of all devices and tables.